# PHP DOMDocument loadhtml. How force not to change markup?

Tags: php, html, xml, domdocument

Hi everyone ho read this :) 
My broblem is with this `$dom_doc = new DOMDocument("1.0", "utf-8")->loadHTML($doc)`

$doc looks like :

```
...
<images>
 <img>
   <file>myfile.jpg</file>
   <desc>My file description</desc>
 </img>
 <img>
   <file>myfile.jpg</file>
   <desc>My file description</desc>
 </img>
</images>
...
```

loadHTML converts this tags into single html tags (`img`, `link` etc)

```
...
<images>
 <img/>
 <file>myfile.jpg</file>
 <desc>My file description</desc>
 <img/>
 <file>myfile.jpg</file>
 <desc>My file description</desc>
</images>
...
```

What should i do force use paired tags?
maybe `loadXML()`, but it do not want to work with xpath correctly. By selector "//images", shows me that nothing found. So I prefer to use `loadHTML`()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not HTML but XML, If you load it as HTML the DOM parser has to parse it according to HTML rules and that mean for example that `img` has no closing tag.

I expect you have some namespace definition in you XML. If this is the case you will have to register an prefix for that namespace.

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<images xmlns="urn:some-namespace">
 <img>
   <file>myfile.jpg</file>
   <desc>My file description</desc>
 </img>
</images>
XML;

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
$xpath->registerNamespace('x', 'urn:some-namespace');

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//x:images/x:img') as $img) {
  var_dump(
    [
      'file' => $xpath->evaluate('string(x:file)', $img),
      'desc' => $xpath->evaluate('string(x:desc)', $img)
    ]
  );
}
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  ["file"]=>
  string(10) "myfile.jpg"
  ["desc"]=>
  string(19) "My file description"
}
```